# Reduce on plateau final model

Tags: deep-learning

I have a questions regarding the training of my final machine-learning model. 
I trained the model using k-fold cross validation and reduced the learning rate with keras `ReduceLROnPlateau` function by a factor of 0.2.

Now I want to train my model on the whole dataset and I am wondering how I should use reduce on plateau now, as my validation set has gone.

The only set left is my test set. Should I monitor the validation loss of the test set instesd during training of the whole model?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: My take would be that even in final training you should work with a validation set since the test set should be data "never seen by the model before" (information leakage!).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Peter. Ja, that makes sense. I guess the best solution is to simply take a certain percentage of the training set for validation and then test on the test set.

Comment: That is the usual approach, exactly. In Keras fit function, you can tell Keras what amount of data to use for validation: https://keras.io/models/sequential/

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful comments Peter!